# How to set minimized child window to be appear in inside parent window in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I have opened window with flag `Qt::Window` inside the parent widget.

Usually if we minimize it, it will go to the task bar of our PC.

But I want it to appear inside the Parent widget, not in the task bar. How to do this?

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for `QMdiArea`?

Comment: yes,Inside mainwindow

Comment: yes what? is `QMdiArea` enough for you or do you need something more than that?

Comment: Thanks for your replay it is enough for me.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer was useful to you it would be helpful to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for a [QMdiArea](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmdiarea.html) widget here:

[image]